# .NET Windows App Not displaying Message Box or writing to a Log file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a .NET 4.0 Windows application with no UI. All the code is in the Program class. The application is located on a network share. This is the basics of what it does.

1. Check the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\ subfolders for
   MSACCESS.EXE to determine what version of Office is installed.

   1. Updates the registry with the Trusted Location to where an MS Access app will be copied to.
   2. Creates a Destination Folder and copies the contents of Master folder to the destination folder.
   3. It starts the MS Access application when all done.
   4. .NET app closes.

I have message box prompts if things fail, like not creating the destination folder for example or not updating the registry. All users except myself (I wrote it!) do NOT get the Message Box prompts OR are able to write to the log file. However the destination folder gets created and files copies to the destination plus the MS Access application starts at the end.

WHY or WHY are all users not able to get the msgbox prompts, update the registry or write to the log?

```
        private static void UpdateTrustedLocationForAccessVersion(string startAppFolder)
    {
        var officeVersionsFound = new List<String>();

        const string officeFolder = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\";

        //Example of the folder we are looking for
        //C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14
        if (Directory.Exists(officeFolder))
        {
            var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(officeFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);                
            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                if (folder.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLower().Substring(officeFolder.Length).StartsWith("office1"))
                {
                    var msAccessFile = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "MSACCESS.EXE", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    if (msAccessFile.Length > 0)
                    {
                        officeVersionsFound.Add(folder.Substring(folder.Length-2));
                        MessageBox.Show(folder.Substring(folder.Length - 2) + " was Found!");
                        WriteToLogFile(folder.Substring(folder.Length - 2) + " was Found!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public static void WriteToLogFile(string logMessage)
    {
        string strLogFile = GetLogFile();
        StreamWriter swLog;

        var strLogMessage = string.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, "(User " + GetUserName() + " on " + GetMachineName() + ") " + logMessage);

        if (!File.Exists(strLogFile))
        {
            swLog = new StreamWriter(strLogFile);
        }
        else
        {
            swLog = File.AppendText(strLogFile);
        }

        swLog.WriteLine(strLogMessage);
        swLog.Close();
    }

    private static string GetLogFile()
    {
        var logFileName = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + DateTime.Today.Month + DateTime.Today.Day + "_Log" + ".txt";
        return _path + logFileName;
    }

    private static string GetUserName()
    {
        return Environment.UserName;
    }

    private static string GetMachineName()
    {
        return Environment.MachineName;
    }
```

Comment: Added code for checking the version of MS ACCESS. The MessageBox.Show is not displaying for all users (Except Me). The WriteToLogFile simply writes to an existing file if created with todays date, other wise a new one is created.

Comment: It works for you on your machine, or on the network share, but not for them. So registry and file system. Virtualisation through lack of permissions, or swallowed exceptions are first two thoughts.

Comment: No use, where is the log file located?

Comment: You should step through the code in a debugger. For one thing, this code will fail if the user's on a 32bit PC, since the Program Files folder is C:\Program Files\ without the (x86) only present on a 64bit PC. Also, keep in mind that if this is a .NET application configured for Partial Trust, you'll find that some operations succeed and others fail, due to the security model for .NET applications launched from Network Shares.

Comment: Does this run for you outside of VS and from the network location? Also where is the writetologfile code if you want help with why it isn't working?

Comment: - The Log file is written to the network share, one level down from where the app resides. 
- I have tried this app locally AND on the network share. It only works for ME.
- I can run it via VS 2010/2012 also with no issue.
- 32/64 bit makes no difference on target machine. I have tested this on uses with both.
-The app DOES WORK EXCEPT for the msgbox, registry and Logging.
-How do I set a ,NET app to run a sFULL TRUST? I thought those issues died with ,NET 1.1?

Comment: I Edited the entry and added the Logging Code. Like I said, the code is fine as it work for me. The other odd thing is that if I run this via Citrix it ALL WORKS. So something is supressing the messages etc.

Comment: are you trying to run it in a setup-package or maybe as service perhaps?

Comment: No setup package. Just build in Release mode and copy the EXE to the network location.

Comment: check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad3f5a91-2d08-4c13-b63a-97bf0fd2bbd8/is-there-an-environmentspecialfolders-enum-to-return-the-programfiles-x86-path-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: OK, so the problem was pretty dumb on my part! I have hard-coded the "Program Files(x86)" path rather than using the Environment as suggested by Viney Pandey (Thanks!). The MessageBox and Writing to the Log was all based on if the Path was found. My hard coded Path was for a 64bit Windows OS, hence the (x86), BUT all the users run 32 bit Windows 7. Therefore their Path is just "Program Files" and NOT "Program Files(x86)" so the whole logging and MessageBox stuff was bypassed.
Thanks to EVERYONE for the suggestions! I just could not see the forest for the trees, so this will make me think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem was pretty dumb on my part! I have hard-coded the "Program Files(x86)" path rather than using the Environment as suggested by Viney Pandey (Thanks!). The MessageBox and Writing to the Log was all based on if the Path was found. My hard coded Path was for a 64bit Windows OS, hence the (x86), BUT all the users run 32 bit Windows 7. Therefore their Path is just "Program Files" and NOT "Program Files(x86)" so the whole logging and MessageBox stuff was bypassed. Thanks to EVERYONE for the suggestions! I just could not see the forest for the trees, so this will make me think!